# How to refresh ListView after deleting element?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have created a listview but when i delete a element, it doesn't refresh. I have tried

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and

```
getListView().invalidateViews();
```

in mainactivity:

```
case R.id.ordini:

                    Ordini O = new Ordini();
                    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager0 = getFragmentManager();
                    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction0 = fragmentManager0
                            .beginTransaction();

                    fragmentTransaction0.replace(R.id.frame, O);
                    fragmentTransaction0.commit();
```

- Ordini.java

  ```
  public class Ordini extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

  int ArraySize;
  CustomAdapterOrdini adapter;
  private List<RowItemOrdini> rowItems;
  Button SendButton;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.ordini, null, false);

  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

      ArraySize = MainActivity.ArrayProdotto.size();
      SendButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.send_btn);

      rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItemOrdini>();

      for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++) {
          RowItemOrdini items = new RowItemOrdini(
                  MainActivity.ArrayProdotto.get(i),
                  R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp,
                  MainActivity.ArrayCode.get(i),
                  MainActivity.ArrayPrezzo.get(i),
                  MainActivity.ArrayColli.get(i),
                  MainActivity.ArrayQuantita.get(i));

          rowItems.add(items);
      }

      adapter = new CustomAdapterOrdini(getActivity(), rowItems);
      setListAdapter(adapter);

      getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);


      SendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "invio ordine in corso... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                      .show();
              SendOrdine();
          }
      });
  }
  @Override
  public void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      getListView().invalidateViews();
  }
  ```
- CustomAdapterOrdini

  ```
  public class CustomAdapterOrdini extends BaseAdapter {

  Context context;
  List<RowItemOrdini> rowItem;

  ImageView  Del;
  TextView Colli, Prezzo, Quantita, Code, Product;




  CustomAdapterOrdini(Context context, List<RowItemOrdini> rowItem) {
      this.context = context;
      this.rowItem = rowItem;

  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {

      return rowItem.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {

      return rowItem.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {

      return rowItem.indexOf(getItem(position));
  }
  @Override
  public boolean  areAllItemsEnabled() {
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
      return false;
  }




  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                  .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_ordini, null);
      }
      Code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prodcode);
      Product = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.PRODOTTO);
      Del = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.del);

      Colli = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.T1);
      Prezzo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.T2);
      Quantita = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.T3);


      Del.setFocusable(true);
      Del.setClickable(true);

      Del.setTag(convertView);

      final RowItemOrdini row_pos = rowItem.get(position);
      // setting the image resource and title
      Del.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp);
      Product.setText(row_pos.getTitle());
      Code.setText(row_pos.getCode());

      Colli.setText(row_pos.getColli());
      Prezzo.setText(row_pos.getPrezzo());
      Quantita.setText(row_pos.getQuantita());

      Del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              // HERE I WANT REFRESH MY LISTVIEW

              MainActivity.ArrayQuantita.remove(0);
              MainActivity.ArrayCode.remove(0);
              MainActivity.ArrayProdotto.remove(0);
              MainActivity.ArrayColli.remove(0);
              MainActivity.ArrayPrezzo.remove(0);

              CustomAdapter.ShowDialog("Elemento eliminato con successo!", context);

          }
      });

      return convertView;

  }
  ```

Can someone help me with listview refresh?
I want refresh my listview in CustomAdapterOrdini or in onResume in Ordini.java.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                // HERE I WANT REFRESH MY LISTVIEW
```

There is a simple way?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declare `ArrayProdotto` in your `MainActivity` and you are display your data from `rowItem` in `CustomAdapterOrdini`. You have to remove your data from both list and call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Like as below code.

```
Del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         // HERE I WANT REFRESH MY LISTVIEW
         MainActivity.ArrayProdotto.remove(position); //Delete from main source
         rowItem.remove(position) // Delete from adapter
         CustomAdapter.ShowDialog("Elemento eliminato con successo!", context);
         notifyDataSetChanged(); // Refresh Adapter

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1). Remove your item from adapter:

```
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
```

2). Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

You should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` every time when you deleting item from adapter. Not only in `onResume`.

Note, that you should remove item from adapter, to change `ListView` items, not from storage(`ArrayList`, `SQLite`, or else).